# Implementing RESTful Architecture on ZOO Project?

Tags: rest, wps, zoo-project

I read in the [WPS 2.0 paper](http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/14-065/14-065.html) on Open GIS webpage that WPS 2.0 can be implemented with a RESTful architecture. I am working on a project using ZOO WPS.

Is there some way to incorporate the RESTful architecture in this?

According to my understanding so far, it seems that the framework is suitable only for SOAP architecture as all message formats are in xml.

Comment: *the WPS 2.0 paper on Open GIS webpage* Add a link, please

Comment: REST requires hypermedia, and XML can be hypermedia, so that in itself shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

From my quick look at the [WPS 2.0 standard](http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/14-065/14-065.html) I see no mention of a RESTful endpoint. In keeping with most OGC standards WPS *may* provide an [HTTP Post/XML](http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/14-065/14-065.html#72) endpoint (**note** this is not SOAP) and a [HTTP GET/KVP](http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/14-065/14-065.html#79) endpoint (**note** this is not RESTful).